# How to fetch only image assets from smart albums with NSPredicate in Swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, ios11, ios12

I want to fetch image assets from all smart albums on the users phone. At the moment I am fetching images and videos, but thats not what I want.

On my research I have always found the same solution but it doesn't seem to work any more since the questions are several years old now. So I can't find any up-to-date solution.

This is the solution I have found

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)

let smartAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
let fetchAssetsResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collection, options: fetchOptions)
```

On executing this lines of code I get the following error message

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate in fetch options: mediaType == 1'
```

Is there any new working solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the help of Bappaditya I have found out that I was using the predicate on the wrong asset fetch. The mediaType key is just for `PHAsset.fetchAsset()` and not for `PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollection()` as I was using it for.

This code is working now

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
let smartAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)

fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)
let fetchAssetsResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collection, options: fetchOptions)
```

Comment: Perfect, I needed to find videos only and it worked well also.

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
let albumName = "Your Album Name" or "Your Album Local Identifier"
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
```

The supported keys are,

[image]

For more details please refer [PHFetchOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phfetchoptions#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014396)

Comment: This doesn't seem to affect the media type or am I wrong? I still want to fetch all albums with all the content, but only the images not videos.

Comment: updated my answer with supported keys for `PHFetchOptions`

Comment: So whats the reason then that I get the error message for an unsupported predicate? MediaType is in the list of supported keys. Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: I think I have found the problem! I will give an answer to myself.